# Modifying attributes dynamically using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is a part of an `HTML` page:

```
<div class="ajax-load">

</div>

<button id="next" class="load-page-2">
```

And here is the `javascript:`

```
$(".load-page2").click(function() {
    $(".ajax-load").load("3.php");
    $.get('4.php', function(data) {
         $('.ajax-load').append(data);
             $.get('5.php', function(data){
                $('.ajax-load').append(data);
            });
        });

     // Now I need to change the class of the #next button

    $("#next").removeClass("load-page2");
    $("#next").addClass("load-page3");
}); // End click function



//Now different functionality for the same button but with class "load-page3" 

$(".load-page3").click(function(){
    // load 6.php 7.php 8.php
});
```

But this does not work. It seems like the button still has the `"load-page2" class` and hence loads `3.php 4.php and 5.php`

Comment: Try using on `$(document).on('click', '.load-page3', function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dynamic properties you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-page2', function(){
    //you code
})
$(document).on('click', '.load-page3', function(){
    //you code
})
```

When you add normal event handlers, those are attached to elements which matches the selectors at the time of the code execution, any changes made to the element attributes after that will not affect the registered handlers.

Comment: Do you know everything about jquery?

Comment: Why does it happen like this?

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra Not sure about everything but he will solve all your problems. :)

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra drinking some Masala chai? :)